# Any idea what this 3-engine beauty is?

Tags: aircraft-identification

Can anybody identify this 3-engine flying boat moored on the ramp?

[image]

Answer (score 30):

This is very likely to be a [Savoia-Marchetti S.66](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savoia-Marchetti_S.66)

The front view is unmistakable (and pretty unique).

[image]

Here's another angle of it, almost certainly moored at the same place

[image]

Comment: Pre-War Italian flying boats are pretty distinctive, aren't they?

Comment: @ZeissIkon Almost _everything_ designed by the Italians is distinctive ;)

Comment: Many thanks for your quick response - much appreciated.

Comment: @Tiger Instead of thanking in comments, you should accept an answer. Have a look at the [tour](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Do any of the background features really match up between the two photos?

Comment: @quietflyer The dock itself in the foreground definitely seems to match.  You can even see that grate to the left of it in both shots.  It's harder to match the far shore, because a small change of angle gives you a completely different view, and it's likely a different focal length on the lens to boot, an effect magnified by distance.  I'd say the 2nd photo is pointed slightly to the right of the first, based on that sandbar in both shots, and the bridge, more visible in the 2nd shot than the first.

Comment: [(background reference point)](https://ibb.co/2YpRgWn)

Comment: @qqjkztd The bridge does match up

Comment: Out of interest, Rex's Hanger (YouTube channel) covers more of the planes evolution and history in [Italy's Weird & Wonderful Twin-Hull Flying Boats | Savoia-Marchetti S.55 & S.66](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IWV0nJQf9eY)

Comment: @quietflyer I'm sure that's the same place. Just like D.Hoffman said. I took qqjkztd's picture and marked some other features that match nice. Green - tree line near the bridge and a wide building just after the trees. Blue - two rightmost pillars and a tower behind them. Also, I'm pretty sure that this bridge is a railway bridge. You can see smoke from a moving train to the right (violet arrows, puffs, not yet dispersed by the wind; not a shape of a smoke from house/factory), and its roughly matches the bridge and shape of the terrain (the violet line, railways). -> https://ibb.co/HVmw6HN

Comment: @quetzalcoatl -- thanks for the note

Comment: I forgot a link, pasted now :)